# Comprehensive book on Kile

Tags: editor, books, latex, kile

Finally, I have decided to migrate from Office to Latex. That is why I have chosen Kile as an editor, for many reasons.

That's why I need a comprehensive book or would be even perfect if there is a video training course on Kile. The reason is that I have never worked with it before.

Could you help me to choose a good starting point on learning Kile,please?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe same as this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-started-with-latex

Comment: @CYREX. Completely different. I have decided to use KILE while he is looking for the best editor, and also I need to find some books or video training courses while in the answers of that question there is no any answer telling about books or resources. So it is different as BLACK and WHITE colors.

Comment: Well i was refering to the help files in there but if you are looking for books for kile i do not see the relation with ubuntu apart from the fact that it is used in ubuntu. Maybe http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/index.html will help.

Comment: I would be very surprised if any books (apart from its own documentation) or training videos exist for Kile in particular. If you have questions though ask over at tex.stackexchange.com and they'll probably get answered.

Comment: @frabjous. Thanks a lot. I didn't guess that there is a tex.stackexchange.com. I will surely ask my question there also.

Answer (score 2):

If Kile's interface is what you're interested in, then its online documentation is a good starting point. You can find it on [Kile's sourceforge page](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/index.html).

If, however, you'd like to learn more about LaTeX itself, then I highly recommend the LaTeX companion (available on [amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201362996)) or, available online, the Not So Short introduction to LaTeX ([1](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/index.html)).