# LaTeX on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: software-recommendation, latex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the easiest way to get started with LaTeX?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-started-with-latex)

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 after decades with Windows. I need to use LaTeX. On Windows I used to install MikTeX then installed TeXnicCenter and it worked. How do I do it on Linux. MikTeX is for Windows only. Is LaTeX already integrated in Ubuntu? But what Editor do you then recommend? I installed Kile but don't get it to compile. Any ideas?
Thanks.